# camel - ftp GenericFileOperationFailedException: File operation failed: 550 CWD failed

Tags: ftp, apache-camel

My camel route is trying to download and unzip a zip file from ftp server (Filezilla).

My Ftp configuration :

- Root directory(home directory) is set to c:\
- thg.ftp.incomingDir=/fileprocessor
- thg.ftp.toDir=/unzip

```
    <camel:route id="unziponFTP">
        <camel:from ref="ZipFileFrom"/> 
        <camel:unmarshal ref="zipFileDataFormat"/>
        <camel:split streaming="true">
            <camel:simple>${body}</camel:simple>                
            <camel:to ref="UnzippedFolder"/> 
        </camel:split>
    </camel:route>
```

unzipped folder name : Week54_09Apr-15Apr

Camel is able to unzip the zip file properly and i can see all the files as well, but I am seeing the exception :

> org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException:
>   File operation failed: 550 CWD failed. "/unzip/Week54_09Apr-15Apr":
>   directory not found.  Cannot change directory to: Week54_09Apr-15Apr.
>   Code: 550     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.doChangeDirectory(FtpOperations.java:775)

Comment: <camel:endpoint id="ZipFileFrom"    uri="ftp://${thg.ftp.username}@${thg.ftp.server}/${thg.ftp.incomingDir}/?password=${thg.ftp.password}&amp;delay=120s&amp;binary=true&amp;reconnectDelay=60s&amp;move=done&amp;moveFailed=error" />
                                                                                                                                                                      
  <camel:endpoint id="UnzippedFolder" uri="ftp://${thg.ftp.username}@${thg.ftp.server}/${thg.ftp.toDir}/?password=${thg.ftp.password}&amp;initialDelay=12000" />